# Is there a way to allow multiple enum tags in one line through clang-format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I find large enums more readable like this:

```
enum class A {
    TAG, OTHER_TAG, OTHER_OTHER_TAG,
    OTHER_OTHER_OTHER_TAG...
};
```

instead of:

```
enum class A {
    TAG,
    OTHER_TAG,
    OTHER_OTHER_TAG,
    ... // you get the picture
};
```

It seems that clang-format can be made to allow that kind of thing in array definitions, Is there a way to do this for enums as well that I'm missing?

Current .clang-format is:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
UseTab: Never
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
ColumnLimit: 80
AccessModifierOffset: -4
FixNamespaceComments: true
NamespaceIndentation: All
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `ColumnLimit` set to, not 0 I hope.

Comment: Added current .clang-format

Comment: And no `//` comments must be present I believe.

Comment: Yep, no `//` comments present in enum declaration.

Comment: Looks like the best they've got is `AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine`, which doesn't do what you want since your enums are bigger. I am in favor of one item per line, though.

Comment: Figured as much, no big deal anyway, mainly curiosity. Thanks folks :)